# Consecutive onclick events on same button triggering separate scripts

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I am learning javascript and started working with using scripts to modify the DOM.

I have a small html file where the user pushes a button and the html changes state. What I am having trouble with is, after the main onclick event, having the same button reset the page to it's original state, i.e. editing the DOM to return to its original mark-up.

This is my file (I know it's simple but it will help me):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My First JavaScript</title>

<style type="text/css">
h3#norm {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #0059D7;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--creating a wrapper to contain and layout the page-->
<div id="wrapper">
<h3 id="norm">Are you new here?</h3>

<!--button for running script-->
<input class="button" type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Yes">

<!--begin javascript to edit html in above line-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//when button is clicked script edits html
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML="<h3>Welcome!!!</h3>";
};

document.getElementById('button').onclick
//-->
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** ADDED MISSING CSS TO QUESTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't put the h3 tag in the javascript innerHTML, as it's repetitive.

2) Learn the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).  Change

```
document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML="<h3>Welcome!!!</h3>";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML = (document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML == "Welcome!!!") ? "Are you new here?" : "Welcome!!!";
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Dan Goodspeed, thanks for the link. I figured there was an operator for this.

Comment: ps. there is a reason I included the <h3>. It helped to alter the styles of the welcome state. Is there a way to include this into the solution? Change the inner HTML AND the id of the parent <h3> tag?

Comment: So what is happening, if you look at the CSS, the <h3 id="norm"> has different styling than the <h3> tag. Basically the point of the whole exercise was to have the text change in content AND have the styling change. This is why adding the <h3> tag when editing the inner HTML helped, it changed the styling. However, I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this that doesn't use invalid HTML. You could go in and doc.getElementById('norm').id = "blank" to change the styles without bad HTML, but them you have an issue reseting the content as you've lost the "norm" handle.

Comment: just noticed the CSS didn't make it through when I originally posted the question. EDIT: added the CSS, not sure how that didn't make it through

Comment: Ok... it's really bad form to have an <h3> inside of a <h3>.  A lot of this would be easier with jQuery... but I guess what would be best for you is to change the inner <h3> to a <span>, and then in your css you can say "h3 span { ... }".  If you're interested in jQuery, adding a class to the h3 would be the proper way to do it.

Comment: Okay, this is what I thought; adding a <span>. Couldn't I just add a class to this h3 and change it the same way with the ternary operator? Edit the document.getElementById('norm').class?

Comment: Yeah, you could probably do something like that.  These days I would do that with jQuery... I'm not sure what the browser support for that function is with regular javascript, if that's something that's important to you.

Comment: Yeah I'll move on to JQuery but just wanted to understand how to do it in JS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not the BEST way, but certainly using the least effort, try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {

    var test = document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML;
    if (test == "Welcome!!!") {
        document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML="Are You New Here?";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('norm').innerHTML= "Welcome!!!";
    }

};
```

A neater way would for example be

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  var norm = document.getElementById('norm'),
      test = "Welcome!!!";
  norm.innerHTML=norm.innerHTML==test?"Are You New Here?":test;
};
```

Comment: Please do not add text more than once. It is a waste.

Comment: A downvote?  Especially since I explained it was probably easiest to understand but NOT best practice?  That seems rather uncalled for.

Comment: So post your better effort instead of teaching noobs poor practises :)

Comment: @mplungjan, Sometimes noobs find it easier to understand something that makes the fewest changes to their own code in the most comprehensible way.  I agree with your comment and appreciate your input.  I would not put a downvote in that situation, but i'm guessing we are not philosophically aligned on that.  Best :-)

Comment: If you count number of unexplained down votes on some of my imnho completely correct posts you would appreciate that I commented on yours :)

Comment: Totally understood.  Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Dan Goodspeed gets the cake for the answer. I was sure there was some type of operator that could do this but had no idea about it. But Bearturns input definitely shows the logic behind solving this problem and would have been my first solution had I not known about the ternary operator. Definitely good input, thanks Bearturns

Comment: ps. there is a reason I included the <h3>. It helped to alter the styles of the welcome state. Is there a way to include this into the solution? Change the inner HTML AND the id of the parent <h3> tag?